# Run code every 24 hours, but only after a specific time

Tags: ios, time

In my apps settings page, users can select to have their data cleared every day, either at 3am, or 3pm, depending on their schedule. Im looking for a way to reliably do this.

So far I have tried storing the seconds since Jan 1, 1970 on install, and then every time time app is opened, I get the current seconds since 1970, and compare them to determine if the number meets or exceeds 86400, which is 24 hours. If it does, I clear the data and replace the stored seconds with the time of the clear, and if it doesn't I do nothing. This would work great if I only wanted to clear the data if its been 24 hours or more since the last clear, but what I really want to do is clear the data if its past the users set time, and a clear hasn't already been completed that day.

For example:

- if the app is installed on May 21st at 6pm, and the user begins to input data, it should clear as long as the current data & time meets or is past May 22nd, at 3am. The 24 hour logic will not not clear it until the date and time meets or exceeds May 22nd, at 6pm.

Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Keep in mind that while 86400 seconds is 24 hours, the time from 3AM one day to 3AM the next day is not necessarily 24 hours. That might or might not matter to your situation.

Comment: How is it not 86400 seconds between 3am on consecutive days? is there not 24 hours between the same time every day?

Comment: No. What happens if summer time (daylight saving time in the USA) started or ended during that period? It could be 23 hours or 25. Also, what if there's a leap second, which happens at times?

Comment: Ah, good point. Thanks for the clarification, ill take that into mind when coming up with a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure how you are planning on handling it(with push notifications/Local notifications/ or a simple check if the user has the app in the foreground)

However, I would create a local notification:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(86400)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Handle your clearing, and reset the notifications for 24-hours later once again.

Silent push notifications would be nice, as you would be able to clear the data every 24 hours, without your user needing to think about or even open the app.  However, you would then need backend logic to handle sending out those notifications to the devices; you are limiting your reset times to 3am or 3pm so I suppose that wouldn't be terrible to implement.

Just keep in mind that you are limited to a 30s runtime.  Also the silent notifications only complete if the app is suspended, if the app has been terminated by the user, the delegate method is not called.

--Edit--

Push notifications would be a little much for this, I must have missed the part saying you wanted this to happen on app start(sorry about that)....

You could write a extension to the `Date` class:

```
func dateByAddingDays(_ daysToAdd: Int) -> Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var days = DateComponents()
    days.day = daysToAdd
    return (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: days, to: self, options: [])
}
```

Save this date however you would like, then on app load compare the saved date to the current date, if it passes your check remove the data.  You don't have to use days here, you can can replace days with hours/minutes etc...  `var hours = DateComponents()` -> `hours.hour = hoursToAdd`

Comment: I only need this to work when the user opens the app. Like if the last clear was at 3am on May 22, and they open at 4pm on May 30, it should just realize that it has to clear and execute some code. I think push notifications are a little overkill for this? Thoughts?